# Using FFMPEG to record a radio stream, how do I save the metadata into a second file

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, metadata

I'm trying to record a radio station for a bit over four hours with FFMPEG so I can listen to the charts with no cost for mobile data later.

Like this, which works fine:

```
ffmpeg -i <STREAM URL REMOVED> -t 04:05:00 -c copy los40_2023_04_22_chart.aac
```

The station transmits metadata which has track info of the songs played.
This data changes all the time

```
 Metadata:
    icy-name        :
    icy-description :
    icy-url         : http://los40.com/
    icy-genre       : Pop
    icy-br          : 56
    StreamTitle     : Ariana Grande,Zedd - Break free
    encoder         : Lavf59.4.101
```

How can I capture the metadata in a seperate file?

Adding

```
-f ffmetadata temp.txt
```

to the command only saves the metadata from the start of the recording, but not the changes.